# JQuery recognize string as function dynamically callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a simple jquery function that I am trying to get ajax to run dynamically. The function works fine when called as such

```
function widget1() { 
    console.log("test");
}

$(function () {                 
  $('#thisbutton').bind('click', function() {
  var htmlString = $("#uid").html();
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/getappobj",
      data: {id:htmlString},
      success: function(data) {
        widget1();
      }
    });
});});
```

but if I try to get the function called dynamically I get an error that the string is not a function

```
$(function () {                 
  $('#thisbutton').bind('click', function() {
  var htmlString = $("#uid").html();
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/getappobj",
      data: {id:htmlString},
      success: function(data) {
        var findit = data[0].widget;//returns "widget1"
        findit();
      }
    });
});});
```

I have tried this every way that I can think of. Using jquery-1.9.1.min.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `widget1` is global, you can call `window[findit]()` to get the function from the window object by name.

You are trying to call a string as a function which of course won't work. You need to use the string to look-up the function to execute.

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'll accept as soon as it lets me. Thanks again.

Comment: Or you can use your own object to hold the functions: `var funcs = {widget1: function(){}};`, then you can do `funcs[findit]();`.